# mod_pagespeed: Combine Javascript, CSS not working with SSL

Tags: apache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I am using mod_pagespeed. When using http, combine js, css and rewrite js and css work fine. However, when I switch to https, none of these four functions work. The apache error log is empty about this.

This is the relevant conf line
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,rewrite_css,combine_css,combine_javascript,insert_dns_prefetch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mod_pagespeed` cannot rewrite HTTPS resources by default, you have to explicitly enable it by one of these options:

1. `ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain` - to tell `mod_pagespeed` to fetch HTTPS resources using HTTP
2. `ModPagespeedLoadFromFile` - to tell `mod_pagespeed` to load HTTPS resources directly from the filesystem.
3. `ModPagespeedFetchHttps` - to tell `mod_pagespeed` to fetch HTTPS resources directly.
4. `ModPagespeedFetchFromModSpdy` - if you have `mod_spdy` installed, to fetch resources using it.

The documentation has more details: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support

Comment: This answer seems not be up-to-date:
"As of version 1.10 HTTPS fetching (FetchHttps) is enabled by default, and PageSpeed no longer requires additional configuration to fetch and optimize resources over https. The alternatives described below, however, are more efficient in situations where they apply." https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/https_support regards, Andreas